# Charging a small 100uF 450V capacitor with a small battery?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, transformer, high-voltage, inverter

How can I easily charge a 450V capacitor with a small battery such as a 1.5V or 9V while stepping the voltage up in between so as to provide a voltage near 450V for the capacitor?

I'm looking to charge this capacitor with either pieces I buy or those I build, but I want the materials not including the capacitor and battery to cost me under $20, preferably under $10. If necessary I can take parts out of other devices, but it would be most preferable just to buy them pre-built.

I've looked up what would be necessary and it looks like I'd need a step up inverter from the small DC voltage (probably around 12V) to the large AC voltage(probably around 220V) then I'd need a 2:1 step up transformer to turn the 220V into around 440V and then I'd need another inverter to turn the 440V AC current into a 440V DC current. I might also need 2 of all of these pieces if I needed to down step the Voltage to finish the circuit, but there might be a way around that. In addition to cases for the battery or batteries. The wiring for all this will be bought separately in addition to a switch if that was a question.

Comment: Geiger counter tubes use in that vicinity of voltage and the following contains a simple power supply http://mightyohm.com/blog/products/geiger-counter/design-files/. Be careful though, it's obviously a dangerous amount of voltage and you seem to have a few misconceptions above so I assume you've never done anything like this before?

Comment: What is the maximum charging time?

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single stage with a flyback converter.  Choosing the ratio of the transformer correctly will be important.  Since it doesn't sound like you need isolation, you can use a autotransformer if you can find one with the right ratio.

Comment: Take a look at disposable camera flashgun circuits - that's  what they do -charge a capacitor to a high voltage from a few volts.

Comment: To respond to the comments in order:
1. I have worked with plenty of circuitry components before with my dad, but this is the first time I've worked with transformers and high-voltages. I plan to use safety equipment (rubber gloves and a voltage meter) actually would it be better to use rubber gloves or to simply only use one hand with the other hand as ground? And where is the best place to find the parts listed in the bill of materials?

Comment: 2. The maximum charging time is rather negligible since I'll probably be taking the capacitor out of this circuit and attaching it to another, being careful to not let the two leads touch anything. Actually do you think it would be better to charge the capacitor and release the charge in two different circuits? Or should I keep it all in one circuit?

Comment: 3. I was going to say I'll refer to the answer someone left for more information, but since it seems he's talking about making an isolated one, where would you suggest looking for an autotransformer?

Comment: 4. I have seen plenty of how-to's about charging high voltage capacitors that are used in camera's by just taking out the circuitry including the capacitor and adjusting it, but I didn't intend on doing any sodering, so I set that idea aside, but then I saw this, http://www.madscientisthut.com/Shopping/agora.cgi?product=Radiation%20Detection&user4=Camera%20Flash%20PCB I think I might just use it since it's pre-built, and goes up to the same voltage as the kind described in the answer below. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Take a look at disposable camera flashgun circuits - that's what they do -charge a capacitor to a high voltage from a few volts." - Jim Dearden I took his advice and found this: http://www.madscientisthut.com/Shopping/agora.cgi?product=Radiation%20Detection&user4=Camera%20Flash%20PCB Which should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

What you could use is a boost converter such as the LT3573: -

[image]

This will charge up a capacitor to 300V. I reckon the parts would cost less than $20 and there are plenty of other similar chips of this type from Linear technology and TI for instance.

The circuit above produces 300Vdc and uses primary voltage sensing to determine the secondary voltage. Using what is known as a [cockroft walton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator) diode-capacitor voltage multiplier could get you much more than this quite easily. You would typically use this type of circuit directly on the transfomer secondary.

TAKE CARE - THESE VOLTAGES ARE QUITE LETHAL AND SCARY

Comment: This sounds quite interesting, but I can't find an image like it anywhere. In fact, the closest thing to it seems to tell a different tale: http://www.linear.com/product/LT3573 In fact the only other direct duplicate of this image was also posted by you...

Comment: Here is the most important advice I can give you - read the data sheet (page 23 I think). I'm being serious - cut straight to the pdf and see what it says: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3573fc.pdf - the number of times I've missed the crown jewels by not reading the data sheet I care not to remember. Always read the data sheet if you have half a belief it might have the answer. It is good advice; the chip - there are plenty that can do this so that advice isn't as useful!!!

Comment: I understand now! So the model number is just a blanket model for a number of variations of circuits, but why would they all be the same model number if they're all for different things? I've really only worked with minor circuitry (things under transformers and high voltage circuits) before this, so I'm making sure I read into everything including safety precautions, so how do the model numbers for these circuits work?

Comment: I also found this online: http://www.madscientisthut.com/Shopping/agora.cgi?product=Radiation%20Detection&user4=Camera%20Flash%20PCB, so I'll probably just order it since it cuts out all that time I would have had to spend finding parts.

Comment: The "I" version is guaranteed over the full -40 to +125ºC temperature range - it's basically the same chip but some are tested more rigourously than others and are probably double the price!! I think the unit you listed will probably do the job but beware that madscientisthut has been flooded out and although I believe them to be reputable (they have some cool circuits) there may be a delay in getting the parts.

Comment: I saw the notice, and I'm fine with the delay. What I'm doing is part of a hobby experiment, and not time sensitive.

Comment: Wait so how should I go about picking an answer to this question, should I just post my link as the answer to my own question with a little bit of an explanation considering that's the option I'm going with? I could select your answer, but people who came to this question, would probably not know where to buy the parts the same way I don't...?

Comment: Well, peterj's comment suggested Geiger counter circuits and this probably led you down your chosen path so ask him to leave a formal answer and accept it  along the way consider upvoting mine unless already done. Leaving an answer of your own needs realistically a circuit rather than a recommendation where to buy something that has limited supply and no long lasting engineering relevance.